# В FireFox 14.0.1 блоку c  border-radius над видео с youtube ломает углы

Tags: firefox, вёрстка

В FF 14.0.1 блоку c `border-radius` над видео с youtube ломает углы. Вот собственно наглядное изображение того, что просиходит:

[image]

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет увеличение не помогло. Уже нашел решение. Может кому понадобиться.

К iframe с флешем добавляем атрибут `wmode="transparent"`, а атрибуту `src ?wmode=transparent`. Данный код исправляет этот баг с FF, а так же проблему в chrome & ie с перекрытием флэшем других элементов.

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте, возможно я ошибаюсь, но у Вас наверно стоит маленкий уровень округление. Попробуйте прописать так:

```
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
```